# Context path for tomcat deployed web application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, virtualhost

I have deployed web application on tomcat7 and now I am looking forward to update Virtual host to map domain name with my application by updating server.xml.
Is my approach correct? 
I am working on ubuntu OS and not sure how to get the context path for my web app. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The context path of your application will be the name of the war file. If you want to override it, you can follow Tomcat's documentation (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

Edit the server.xml in the conf folder of the tomcat installation and make the following changes.

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

<Context path="/yoururl" docBase="YourApp" useHttpOnly="false">
<Manager pathname="" />
</Context>

</Host>
```

Comment: I have a tomcat on machine with ip x.x.x.x and port 8080. How would I configure domain name in tomcat to point it to my deployed application?